# Disabling Prev and next buttons(keboard) of select box in android and iphone

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

i am using jquery mobile and work light to develop hybrid mobile application. i want to disable prev and next buttons in keyboard of android or iphone.

can any one please help me to do above one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cordova keyboard plugin that can do that for you

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard

you can either setup the plugin with the 
HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar preference set to true.

or in your app run the function

```
Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(true);
```